# wcCategory.ascx file use in Gridview or detailsView cell

Tags: asp.net

Work on Asp.Net vs 08 C#,use northwind database . I want wcCategory.ascx file use on gridview cell

**Below in my wcCategory.ascx file**

```
       <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>

     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<cc1:PopupControlExtender ID="TextBox1_PopupControlExtender" runat="server" 
    DynamicServicePath="" Enabled="True" ExtenderControlID="" PopupControlID="pnlPopeUp"
    TargetControlID="TextBox1">
</cc1:PopupControlExtender>

     <asp:Panel ID="pnlPopeUp" runat="server">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataKeyNames="CategoryID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
             onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CategoryID" InsertVisible="False" 
            SortExpression="CategoryID">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CategoryID") %>'></asp:Label>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblCategoryID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CategoryID") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CategoryName" HeaderText="CategoryName" 
            SortExpression="CategoryName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" 
            SortExpression="Description" />
        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthwindConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [CategoryID], [CategoryName], [Description] FROM [Categories]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
</asp:Panel>



</ContentTemplate>

</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Bellow is my .aspx file

```
<div>

          <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="ProductID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ProductID" InsertVisible="False" 
                SortExpression="ProductID">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductID") %>'></asp:Label>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ProductID") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ProductName" SortExpression="ProductName">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ProductName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ProductName") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SupplierID" SortExpression="SupplierID">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SupplierID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SupplierID") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CategoryID" SortExpression="CategoryID">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CategoryID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    <br />

                    <br />
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="QuantityPerUnit" 
                SortExpression="QuantityPerUnit">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("QuantityPerUnit") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("QuantityPerUnit") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:NorthwindConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [ProductID], [ProductName], [SupplierID], [CategoryID], [QuantityPerUnit] FROM [Products]">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>

        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />    
    </div>
```

I want my .ascx file use on gridview Category cell

Answer (score 0):

Use a placeholder and on rowdatabound use findcontrol to find the placeholder and use loadcontrol to add your usercontrol to the controls collection of the placeholder.  Does that help?